# On Duplicate Key update - MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

I have a MySQL Statement to insert data to 4 rows at a time. The `insert` is working but I'm having difficulty with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

I'm getting an error: *`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''count = VALUES(11, 22, 33, 44)'' at line 15`*

Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, dept, date, count)
VALUES
(1, 4, 2018-01-15, 3),
(2, 3, 2018-01-15, 4),
(3, 3, 2018-01-15, 14),
(4, 2, 2018-01-15, 11)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
count = VALUES(11, 22, 33, 44)
```

I tried to wraps the dept and count update with `''` but that didn't help. Is there a better way to update the `count` on DUPLICATES. Could you please help! Thanks!

Comment: `count` is a semi-reserved word; suggest you either change the column name or add backtics around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument to `VALUES()` is supposed to be the name of a column being inserted into. It will use the value that would have been inserted into that column if there hadn't been a duplication.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, dept, date, count)
VALUES
(1, 4, 2018-01-15, 3),
(2, 3, 2018-01-15, 4),
(3, 3, 2018-01-15, 14),
(4, 2, 2018-01-15, 11)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
count = VALUES(count)
```

If `id =  1` already exists, this will set its count to `3` and leave all the other columns unchanged.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It actually worked! I had an extra `'` that I fixed after seeing your comment. Thank you and thanks to @Bramar!!

Comment: If you want to set multiple columns, it's `dept = VALUES(dept), date = VALUES(date), count = VALUES(count)`

Comment: @Barmar Yup, that's what I did. Thanks a lot!